# How to recover from a segmentation fault

Tags: postgresql, errors, shutdown

Postgresql 11 running on a Centros RHEL 7. 
Suddenly BD crashed and service went down.

```
service postgresql-11.service status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status postgresql-11.service
Segmentation fault
```

Last log:

```
LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-09-05 10:19:08 UTC
LOG:  could not stat file "./base/13877/2617_vm": Input/output error
LOG:  could not stat file "./base/13877/5002": Input/output error
LOG:  could not stat file "./base/13877/13745": Input/output error
LOG:  could not stat file "./base/13877/13728_fsm": Input/output error
LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
LOG:  redo starts at 836/A34031F0
LOG:  incorrect resource manager data checksum in record at 836/A35B25F8
LOG:  redo done at 836/A35B2368
LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2019-09-05 10:17:18.321885+00
LOG:  checkpoint starting: end-of-recovery immediate
LOG:  request to flush past end of generated WAL; request 836/AE344938, currpos 836/A35B25F8
CONTEXT:  writing block 0 of relation base/16384/2619_vm
FATAL:  xlog flush request 836/AE344938 is not satisfied --- flushed only to 836/A35B25F8
CONTEXT:  writing block 0 of relation base/16384/2619_vm
LOG:  startup process (PID 43658) exited with exit code 1
LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I have found some more messages:

```
 WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
 DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
 HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode x(5)
```

How to proceed in this situation?

Comment: Sounds like a broken disk. Get out your backups.

Comment: You mean replacing the disks? @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Yes. `Input/output error` seems pretty suggestive. Of course, check the kernel logs and test the hardware to make sure that is really the problem.

Comment: It is not clear who it is that is seg faulting here, perhaps "/bin/systemctl"?  It doesn't seem to be postgres.  But you do seem to have corrupted disks or file system.